# How to inherit a package or a class in R?

Tags: oop, r, package

I am using a package where I want to add an additional option to its main function and change the content in the main function accordingly. Other than that, I would like to use the package as it is right now.

What is the best way to do this? Any references would be appreciated.

Comment: That seems an unacceptably vague request. You should put some specifics forward.

Comment: @DWin Well, I am not sure how specifics would help here. I want to know how to change main function of a package without rewriting whole package.

Comment: As written I interpreted your question to mean you had written the package yourself. As became apparent that was not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think your change is needed by the rest of the world, too:

1. Contact the maintainer (`packageDescription ("pkgName") $ Maintainer`),
2. explain your change and
3. attach patches for code and documentation to the email?

If only you yourself need the change / want to try around locally:

- `? fix`
- see also `? assignInNamespace`
- get the source (packages on CRAN should be FOSS, but better read the license), make your chagne & install that package locally.
- if you need to insert a bit of code (like an extra output statement): `? trace`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't think you understand my question. I am not asking about process of publishing changed code. I want to change existing package and try it out before that.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did.

1. Create another function copied from the main function of the given package.
2. Change the function as you want.
3. If you need to use internal function of the package (or class), use `<package name>:::` in front of the function name.
4. Make your result inherited from the class you want.

For example, `class(results) <- c("rpart","nnet")`

Comment: david, that is close to the `fix` approach - just that `fix` assigns the resulting function to the same name the original one has. The original is then masked by your version (and still accessible via `pkgname::function`).